# Python: Tkinter to Shutdown, Restart and Sleep

Tags: python, python-2.7, tkinter, subprocess

I am currently developing a small but basic applictaion using tkinter to run on my windows startup so I can have a little menu for the different things I want to open. For example, I currently have buttons to launch a few games I play and buttons to launch Skype, Steam etc. But I am also adding buttons to the menu to Shutdown, Restart and make my computer Sleep. SO far the code I have is fairly basic but still here it is:

```
from Tkinter import *
import os, sys, subprocess

win=Tk()

b1 = Button(win, text = "SKYPE")
b2 = Button(win, text = "STEAM", command = lambda: os.startfile("C:\Program Files (x86)\Steam\Steam.exe"))
b3 = Button(win, text = "GOOGLE")

b4 = Button(win, text = "CS:GO")
b5 = Button(win, text = "RUST")
b6 = Button(win, text = "PPIRACY")
b7 = Button(win, text = "TERRARIA")

b8 = Button(win, text = "SHUTDOWN", command = lambda: subprocess.call(["shutdown.exe", "-f", "-s", "-t", "0"]))
b9 = Button(win, text = "SLEEP", command = lambda: subprocess.call(["sleep.exe", "-f", "-s", "-t", "0"]))
b10 = Button(win, text = "RESTART", command = lambda: subprocess.call(["restart.exe", "-f", "-s", "-t", "0"]))


l = Label(win, text = "Apps")
k = Label(win, text = "Games")
j = Label(win, text = "Misc")

l.grid(row = 0, column = 0, padx = 10, pady = 10)
k.grid(row = 0, column = 1, padx = 10, pady = 10)
j.grid(row = 0, column = 2, padx = 10, pady = 10)

b1.grid(row = 1, column = 0, padx = 10, pady = 10)
b2.grid(row = 2, column = 0, padx = 10, pady = 10)
b3.grid(row = 3, column = 0, padx = 10, pady = 10)

b4.grid(row = 1, column = 1, padx = 10, pady = 10)
b5.grid(row = 2, column = 1, padx = 10, pady = 10)
b6.grid(row = 3, column = 1, padx = 10, pady = 10)
b7.grid(row = 4, column = 1, padx = 10, pady = 10)

b8.grid(row = 1, column = 2, padx = 10, pady = 10)
b9.grid(row = 2, column = 2, padx = 10, pady = 10)
b10.grid(row = 3, column = 2, padx = 10, pady = 10)

mainloop()
```

As you can see my buttons 8, 9 and 10 are all to do these three things. The shutdown works fine so I thought maybe lets try the same command but with sleep.exe or restart.exe (Thought I'd give it a try) But obviously I am getting the error

```
Exception in Tkinter callback
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python27\lib\lib-tk\Tkinter.py", line 1470, in __call__
    return self.func(*args)
  File "C:\Users\NAME\Desktop\test.py", line 17, in <lambda>
    b10 = Button(win, text = "RESTART", command = lambda: subprocess.call(["restart.exe", "-f", "-s", "-t", "0"]))
  File "C:\Python27\lib\subprocess.py", line 522, in call
    return Popen(*popenargs, **kwargs).wait()
  File "C:\Python27\lib\subprocess.py", line 709, in __init__
    errread, errwrite)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\subprocess.py", line 957, in _execute_child
    startupinfo)
WindowsError: [Error 2] The system cannot find the file specified
```

And then for sleep the same again but obviously for making the system sleep.

What would be the way for me to go about shutdown, sleep and restart for me then if that does not work? I am currently on Windows 8.1 if that makes a difference. Thanks for any help.

Comment: how about using Windows Task Scheduler for these tasks?

Answer (score 1):

To get the system to restart on the line of:

```
b10 = Button(win, text = "RESTART", command = lambda: subprocess.call(["shutdown.exe", "-f", "-s", "-t", "0"]))
```

You must change the -s to a -r to restart. The only part I need to fix now is the computer not sleeping with -h (hibernate) Not sure of any other ways to do this on windows 8.1 as -hg does not work.

Answer (score 1):

Sleep computer (from [docs](http://www.howtogeek.com/howto/windows-vista/quick-tip-create-shutdown-restart-lock-icons-in-windows-vista/)):

```
b9 = Button(win, text = "SLEEP", command = lambda: subprocess.call(['rundll32.exe', 'powrprof.dll', 'SetSuspendState','0','1','0']))
```

Hibernate:

```
b9 = Button(win, text = "SLEEP", command = lambda: subprocess.call(['rundll32.exe', 'powrprof.dll', 'SetSuspendState']))
```

Restart system:

```
b10 = Button(win, text = "RESTART", command = lambda: subprocess.call(["shutdown.exe", "-f", "-r", "-t", "0"]))
```

Comment: Will try this now. Thank you for the answer. But do you know of any other way to do so without any extra installations? So if I ever went to a friends tried on there computer I wouldn't have to install anything to sleep?

Comment: Tried the updated answer but brought up the ping.exe for 5 seconds then closes and nothing happens after. So I just when to the link above the 5 second sleep line and noticed the PowerShell way to do it. So may give that a try to sleep. But really would be best without any extra installations.

Comment: Ok, but what do you want to do with sleep?

Comment: It seems I misunderstood what you want. If you want "Sleep Computer" you can do this: `b9 = Button(win, text = "SLEEP", command = lambda: subprocess.call(['rundll32.exe', 'powrprof.dll', 'SetSuspendState','0','1','0']))`

Comment: I updated my answer with sleep and hibernate solutions.

Comment: It seems like the hibernate and sleep options both do the same.. Maybe it is because hibernation is not disasbled on my pc?